# Transforming English sentences into propositions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am facing difficulty in converting the natural language (English sentences) into propositions.

For example: "The automated reply cannot be sent when the file system is full"

The above sentence is being referred from a discrete mathematics book, where p denote “The automated reply can be sent” and and q denote “The file system is full." Consequently the suggested solution from the book is q → ¬p.

But my approach was as follows:

I represented the sentence "The system is full" as p and the sentence "The automatic reply can be sent" as q, and thus the entire statement as  p → ¬q.

I want to know whether my approach is fine.
If it is  wrong, can someone please explain about where I went wrong?

**UPDATE**

Example 2:

"Only if Arun passes the exam will Arun get his license"

For the above sentence,

**Books Approach**

P = Arun passes the exam
Q = Arun will get his license

Solution :  Q -> P

**My Approach**

Since the sentence can be re framed as "If Arun passes the exam, then he will get his license", (If P, then Q) I assumed the solution as P -> Q.

Can someone please explain the difference between the above two approaches?

Comment: The more I see these exercises on natural language translations to formal language the more I wonder... WHY? But that's not your problem... Sorry ArunKumar but I can't figure out what exactly are you asking. Can you be more specific? add examples? applications?

Comment: The suggested solution for the above statement is  q → ¬p. But I just want to know where my approach fails. I have mentioned my approach at the end of my question.

Comment: Mmm... As far as i can see you simply switched the names of the predicates and then switched also the predicate order in the sentence thus not actually changing anything from the suggested solution.

Comment: thanks a lot @Lorenzo.. Can u please take a look on the update of my question?

Answer (score 1):

"If Arun passes the exam then he will get his license" means that passing the exam would allow him to get his license, but there might be other ways to do it. It's like saying "if something is an apple, then it is red". This statement says that apple-ness is a "reason" for being red - but there are lots of things which are red but aren't apples.

"Only if Arun passes the exam will he get his license" means that a) there is no way to get the license without passing the exam, and b) he might have to do other things as well as pass the exam in order to get his license. So we can't say $P \implies Q$, since passing the exam might not be enough to get a license. But we can say that $Q \implies P$; think about it in retrospect. Suppose that, after the fact, we know that Arun got his license. Then we can conclude that he must have passed his exam, because "only if Arun passes the exam will he get his license". In other words, *if* Arun got his license, *then* he must have passed the exam.

Answer (score 0):

Your "approach" is fine. You gave the same answer, only you switched the names of p and q. You are free to choose the names of the sentences as you like and your answer will only agree with someone else's if you both chose the same names.

Comment: thanks @cocoahomology.  Can u please take a look on the update of my question?

Comment: Your new question has a different problem, because your solution is incorrect. "If Arun passes the exam, then he will get his license" does not mean the same as "Only if Arun passes the exam will Arun get his license". For the first sentence, it is possible that Arun could fail the exam and they give him his license anyway. For the second sentence this situation is not possible. You should go back to the textbook and read over the meanings of "if" and "only if" carefully.